# I'm having trouble setting the width of columns and overall table width using a JQuery table (inherited code)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a site with an index of stories in a database as one of its pages (that's intended to be four columns wide and ten rows high), however the spacing is both inconsistent and cannot (it seems) be set to a narrower overall width. A developer I was consulting with said that it's the limitations of JQuery tables, but I feel there must be some workaround for this. Here's what it looks like (top) and how I'd like it to look (bottom):

[Index page as is vs desired look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g58W.png)

And here's the salient code:

```
  <table id="stories" class="table mt-3 pb-3">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="d-flex mt-3">
        <a class="fw-bold menu-page-link menu-page-link-green me-2" href="<?= base_url('/submit')?>">Submit a Piece</a>
        <a class="fw-bold menu-page-link menu-page-link-blue me-2" href="<?= base_url('/home')?>">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
#stories_wrapper .row:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}

.table>:not(caption)>*>* {
    border-width: 0px;
}

.table tbody tr td {
    padding: 0px 5px;
}

.table tbody tr {
    display: none;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+1),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+2),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+3),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+4),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+5),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+6),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+7),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+8),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+9),
.table tbody tr:nth-of-type(40n+10) {
    display: table-row;
}

.table>:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 0px;
}

table {
    border-top: 2px solid #000000 !important;
    /* background: #caf0fe; */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
</style>
<script>
const pageLength = 40;
const removeColIndex2 = 2;
const removeColIndex3 = 3;

(function($){
    var table = $('#stories').DataTable({
        "pagingType": 'full_numbers',
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "responsive": true,
        'pageLength': pageLength,
        'ajax': {
            url: baseUrl + '/ajax/story-index-load',
            type: 'post',
            data: function(d) {
                d.sort = $('.btn-story-sort[disabled]').attr('data-value'),
                d.isMobile = window.outerWidth < 768 ? 1 : 0
            }
        },
        'drawCallback': function(settings){
            var $api = this.api();
            var pages = $api.page.info().pages;

            if (pages == 1) {
                $('#stories_paginate').hide();
            } else {
                $('#stories_paginate').show();
            }
        }
    });

    if (window.outerWidth < 768) {
        table.column(removeColIndex2).visible(false);
        table.column(removeColIndex3).visible(false);
    }
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

1. Setting window or table width values to less than 768 doesn't seem to do anything.
2. Changing pageLength or removing *.table tbody tr:nth-of-type* rows shows fewer rows, but does nothing to change the column widths
3. Setting "autoWidth" to "true" also doesn't seem to affect anything.